# Why can’t I go to the island in new leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

So I looked at a bunch of things and I followed it but it didn’t work? I paid my 39,000 bells but I wasn’t online the next day... Can I still get it or not? I did everything necessary I just can’t get it!

Answer (score 1):

If you've already paid off the loan, you should have access to the island.

Tortimer should pop up in the main menu screen when attempting to travel to your town. Afterwards, talk to him at the dock located on the beach. The next day, you can travel to the island.

If you tried this and it didn't work, we may need more details on your issue.